# Spring Boot War eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I've attempted to use the spring boot starter at https://start.spring.io/ to create a web project with war packaging. I'm using gradle and am able to produce a "hello world" war that works when deployed to an external instance of tomcat 8.5. I would like to use the eclipse server integration but it's not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iwnw.png)

Has anyone been able to integrate with the eclipse tomcat? It would be really useful to have this integration instead of needing to copy the war to an external tomcat container...

Comment: In what *way* is it "not working"?

Comment: figured it out. based on this post https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/496